# C++ Creating Object Outside of Class

Tags: c++, class, object, access-violation

I am currently learning c++ and trying some stupid and simple things. Here is my class:

```
     class CRectangle
            {
                int x,y;
            public:
                //  CRectangle(){};
                int pb;
                int *ptr;
                void setValues(int,int);
                int* allocateArray(int);
                void changeVariable(CRectangle);
                friend void mett(); // !!
                ~CRectangle();
            };

        void CRectangle::setValues(int a, int b)
        {
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }

        void mett()
        {
           CRectangle t;
           t.x =2;
           t.pb = 3;
           t.setValues(5,5);
        } 

        void CRectangle::changeVariable(CRectangle obj)
        {
          (*this).pb = obj.pb;
          //obj.pb = 50;
        }
        CRectangle::~CRectangle()
        {
        //delete [] ptr;
        }
```

In main method, I have tried two things:
First One:

```
int main()
{
mett();
}
```

I simply created one class object in mett() method, and made some variable assignment, however it throws access violation error. I tried to define method as a friend, it didn't matter. Still same error. Also tried with global CRectangle object, result was same.

Second one:

```
int main()
{
    CRectangle obj;
    CRectangle obj2;
    obj.pb = 100;
    obj2.pb = 180;
    cout << obj.pb << "\n";
    obj.changeVariable(obj2);
    cout << obj.pb << endl;
}
```

Again, when I try this, it throws Access Violation error. I solved the problem 
by defining CRectangle parameter as const CRectangle& obj, however stil curious about the reason of error. 

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The problem was trying to delete uninitialized pointer in destructor. I didn't put it at first, thought it was highly unrelevant. Sorry for that.

Comment: Does your `~CRectangle` destructor do something with `ptr` (which was never initialized)?

Comment: please use smart pointer instead of raw pointer

Comment: @BryanChen After learning the basics, I will look at it and other advanced c++ topics. For now my priority is learning basic class,pointer,template mechanism. Thanks for your advice (-;

Comment: Your destructor is running at the end of mett(). If that destructor is deleting an uninitialized pointer that is your problem.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP thank you so much! I just deleted ptr line and related part in that destructor, it worked like a charm. I never thought destructor was the problem so I didn't put it here. Really, thanks. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted compiles, links (once the missing destructor is defined), and runs without any problems.

I see nothing wrong with the portion of the code you posted. Your problem lies in the parts of the class that you left out.

Based on the names of the other class methods, and some of the class members, it's fairly obvious that your class allocates and deallocates some storage on the heap. It's almost a certainty that your bug lies in that part of your code.

Comment: Well, I have never used allocateArray method while trying to run mett(). just now, I deleted all unnecessary methods that I didn't use and tried again. Got the same error. Using visual studio 2012. Would you paste your working code to pastebin and send here? I'd be really appreciated

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FCrYMUqd is the exact code you posted, with no changes. Works fine.

Comment: Thanks, seems my problem is to delete a pointer (which is never initialized ) in an destructor.